# Ajax : force HTTP/1.0

Tags: ajax, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, http-1.0

About everything is in the title.

I need to communicate with a server using HTTP/1.0

I didn't find the attribute or option to do this in xhr.setRequestHeader()

Any idead please ?

Thank you all !